# how to change height row in datagrid using C# on Windows-mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to change height row in datagrid using C# on Windows-mobile?

Answer (score 0):

From .NET CF 3.5 you can use the property PreferredRowHeight

```
dataGrid.PreferredRowHeight = 18;
```

As far as I know there is no way to do it in .NET CF versions prior to 3.5.